# Python: Change behaviour of [] list instatiation/comprehension

Tags: python, object, overloading, constructor-overloading

I am working on a solo project and I find myself using very often the following:

```py
list_obj = list(map(func, list_obj))
```

I want to just add the map functionality to the list class to avoid bloat and make it easier for me, so I created the class:

```py
class list(list):
    def map(self, func):
        return type(self)(map(func, self))
```

This works fine when creating instances of lists using list(), but the issue is that instantiating a list using brackets [] or list comprehensions returns an instance of list with the old behavior. Is there a way to overload these instantiation methods?

Comment: Overriding *list* is a bad idea

Comment: Why not just use `[f(i) for i in list_obj]`, it's the "pythonic" way

Comment: My functions are typically lambda expressions, which would turn list comprehensions a bit uglier, eg `[(lambda x:g(x))(i) for i in list_obj)]` (in a way that g could not be written `[g(i) for i in list_obj]`)

Comment: Also, my intention is to concatenate several of these methods, eg `list_obj.map(f1).filter(f2).map(f3)...`, which would be tedious and unwieldy doing list comprehensions.

Comment: Then you could always write:  `temp = lambda ......; [temp(i) for i in list_obj]`.  Or you could write your own function `listmap` that takes the same arguments as `map` and turns the generator into a `list`.  You really don't want to be subclassing list.

Comment: I don't think you can change the behavior of `[]` (or comprehensions) in the code. They must be defined at the level of the interpreter.

Comment: No, not without going to absurd lengths (e.g. pre-processing, ast hacks, etc etc)

Comment: @George no, that doesn't make any sense. You should just do `[g(i) for i in list_obj]`. Every lambda expression that you would pass to map is of the form `map(lambda x: <some expression with x>, whatever)` can just be `[<some expression with x> for x in whatever]`. Just use list comprehensions in that case

Comment: @George as for your example of mapping/filtering together, well, the whole point of list comprehensions is to allow for expressive mapping/filtering operations. So indeed, `list_obj.filter(predicate).map(f)` is just `[f(x) for x in list_obj if preciate(x)]`, with your `.map. filter map` example, you can use: `[f3(x) for x in map(f1, list_obj) if f2(x)]`

Comment: if it really gets longer, use intermediate variables. This can remain efficient if you use *generator expressions* which are lazy, and only eagerly evaluating the last step as a list comprehension. Which would be better than what you are doing by doing eager implementations of `map` and `filter`. Also note, if you can live without list-literals, you can always use `MySubclass(<gen expression>)` instead of list comprehensions.